# Diferencia entre Struct y un tipo incompleto Struct

Tags: c, struct

A la hora de declarar estos dos struct, ¿cuáles son sus diferencias?¿Cambian los ámbitos desde donde pueden ser invocados?

Struct general:

```
typedef struct Etapa{
  int h, m, s;
}Etapa;                       

Etapa etapas[3];
Etapa *puntero_etapa = etapas;
```

Struct anonimo:

```
typedef struct{
  int h, m, s;
}Etapa;                       

Etapa etapas[3];
Etapa *puntero_etapa = etapas;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El segundo caso no es un struct incompleto sino, como indicas posteriormente, anónimo.

La única diferencia enter ambos es que el segundo únicamente se podrá crear usando el alias:

```
Etapa variable;
struct /* ¿Que ponemos aqui? */ variable2; // <-- no compila
```

Mientras que en el primer caso puedes crear la estructura usando su nombre o el alias:

```
Etapa variable;
struct Etapa variable;
```

¿Alguna ventaja del tener estructuras con nombre?

La única que se me ocurre es que si una estructura no tiene nombre no puedes declarar punteros a la misma dentro de la propia estructura... algo necesario para crear listas enlazadas...

```
struct Nodo
{
  struct Nodo* sig;
};
```

Por supuesto, el alias no es necesario declararlo a la vez que se declara la estructura... suele ser más legible declararlo en una línea independiente:

```
struct Etapa
{
  // ...
};

typedef struct Etapa Etapa;
```